# Calling master detail from server using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and I need to call Master-child details from many tables.

I have one main SQl table and child data in 4 other SQL tables. I need to display all data in single page.

Should I use single ajax call to retrieve all data from server or Should I make separate calls to get each data. I am thinking of using `$q.all()` in angular js. I started to use Second way . Hope it is fine

```
$scope.p1 = $http.get('/p1', {cache: false});
$scope.p2 = $http.get('/p2', {'cache': false});

$q.all([$scope.p1, $scope.p2]).then(function(values) {
    $scope.p1= values[0];
$scope.p2 =  values[1];
});
```

Now I can use ng-repeat in my template to iterate each variable and display data. pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't think you should switch p1/2 from promises to Array types. just pass the requests directly to $.all.

Yea you can fetch your data this way, but how long will each call take?
Is the detail view always visible?

Comment: I have done a single query using subquery and get all the data in single row (multiple items separated with commas) and passing to angular JS. In frontend I just call only single ajax call and get all the results.

Comment: With the information you given in this question it's hard to say something like, 
"It'd be better if you did XXX".

What you have stated sounds fine.